# INNER JOIN & MAX issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I have got the following table in which we store project plans:

```
ID    PROJECT_NAME   MILESTONE_NAME
```

All milestones start with a number such as "0.1 - Milestone Description".

I would like to retrieve the MAX MILESTONE_NAME ordered by project.

I used the following code but it doesn't work...

```
SELECT Sheet1.[PROJECT_NAME], MAX(Sheet1.[MILESTONE_NAME])
FROM Sheet1 INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS Sheet1_1 ON (Sheet1.[PROJECT_NAME] = Sheet1_1.[PROJECT_NAME]) AND (Sheet1.[MILESTONE_NAME] = Sheet1_1.[MILESTONE_NAME])
ORDER BY Sheet1.[PROJECT_NAME]
```

It says the PROJECT_NAME is out of the aggregated function.

Do you guys have any idea how I should move forward?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `GROUP BY Sheet1.[PROJECT_NAME]`.

Try :

```
SELECT Sheet1.[PROJECT_NAME], MAX(Sheet1.[MILESTONE_NAME])
FROM Sheet1
    INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS Sheet1_1 ON (Sheet1.[PROJECT_NAME] = Sheet1_1.[PROJECT_NAME])
        AND (Sheet1.[MILESTONE_NAME] = Sheet1_1.[MILESTONE_NAME])
GROUP BY Sheet1.[PROJECT_NAME]
ORDER BY Sheet1.[PROJECT_NAME]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to the query:

```
GROUP BY Sheet1.[PROJECT_NAME];
```